# How to allow both numbers and decimals in html input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a page in which i am getting an input of type number, as well as i, have used validation to check when there is no input as well as to not allow for special characters or any other characters except numbers.It works fine when we use numbers like 5 ,10 ,33534 but when we use numbers 5.5,10.75 it popups the validation can anyone tell me how to accept both the numbers and float values with the validation.
 I have tried using step in html input but it show the validation message when i use float numbers.

Html:

```
<label class="item item-input InputFormFull">
                <span class="input-label">
                  {{'cost_message' | translate}}
                </span>
                 <input type="number" placeholder="{{'cost_message' | translate}}" step=".01" 
                  ng-model="vm.trade.cost" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()">
              </label>
```

Javascript:

```
if (!isValid(d.field)) {errors.push(d.name + $translate.instant('{{"vempty_message" | translate}}'));}
        // if (isNaN(d.field)) {errors.push('No special characters allowed in ' + d.name);}
        if (isNaN(d.field)) {errors.push($translate.instant('{{"vspecalchar_message" | translate}}'));}
        if (isValid(d.field)) {
          d.field =  d.field.toString();
          if (format.test(d.field)) {errors.push('Special characters not allowed');}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach in such situation would be use of regular expressions.

```
var valid = /^([\d]+(\.)?[\d])?([\d])?$/.test(d.field);
```

this expression here would check for your desired validation and return a boolean value accordingly.

You will find plenty of tools online to play with regular expressions.